# Как правильно использовать async await?

Tags: javascript

В файле api.ts

```
export const searchMovie = async (keyword: string | number) => {
  const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/search-by-keyword?keyword=${keyword}`, options);
  return checkResponse(response)
}

const checkResponse = (response: Response) => {
  response.ok ? response.json() : Promise.reject(`Ошибка: ${response.status}`)
}
```

В другом файле

```
  async function handleSubmit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = await searchMovie(input)

  }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста:

1. Если вывести в консоль data, то там undefined. В другом файле нужно использовать цепочку then? Т.е. это норм что в одном async/await, а в другом then?
2. Мне нужно получить данные с сервера, потом отправить их в стор и обработать ошибку. Через цепочки then я сделал, но как сделать без then ?

Через then сделано так, но я хочу этот код переписать на async/await и не понимаю как правильно это делается:

```
  function handleSubmit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();

    searchMovie(input)
      .then((data: Movies) => {
        dispatch(showPreloader());
        dispatch(searchAction(data));
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      .finally(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          dispatch(hidePreloader());
        }, 500);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема с кодом

```
const checkResponse = (response: Response) => {
  response.ok ? response.json() : Promise.reject(`Ошибка: ${response.status}`)
}
```

В том, что функция `checkResponse` ничего не возвращает. Чтобы она начала возвращать что-то, нужно либо добавить `return`

```
return response.ok ? response.json() : Promise.reject(`Ошибка: ${response.status}`)
```

либо убрать фигурные скобки

```
const checkResponse = (response: Response) => 
  response.ok ? response.json() : Promise.reject(`Ошибка: ${response.status}`)
```

---

`.then` и остальное переводится в `async/await` один к одному, а именно просто убирая `then`, а вместо `catch` и `finally` используя ключевые слова

```
try {
    var data: Movies = await searchMovie(input)
    dispatch(showPreloader());
    dispatch(searchAction(data));
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
} finally {
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(hidePreloader());
    }, 500);
};
```

Comment: почему во всяких примерах/справках не всегда используется try/catch? И надо ли мне использовать try/catch в searchMovie в файле api ?

Comment: @qweezz, `try..catch` используется тогда, когда Promise может перейти в статус `rejected`, в этом случае при использовании `await` кинется исключение.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!